# Jquery ajax calls delayed response on HTTPs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, https

I have 2 environments, Dev and QA, Dev has no HTTP where QA has HTTPS, My code imports contacts from Google. I make an ajax call to get the contacts,
Problem is that in Dev it works fine, but in QA it just halts the browser while importing (though the import is running on backend and data is being saved in Database )

I dont get anything on console, In the network tab in Chrome, I see that the response is not being received.

Here is part of my snippet .

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url :"index.php?page=AJAX&action=importSocial",
                    data: {'import':importSource},
                    success: function(output) {
                        if(output=='multiple'){

                        }else if(output.indexOf("getFB") >0){

                            window.location = output;
                            //alert(output+output.length);
                        }else{

                            window.location = window.location.href;


                        }
                    }
        });
```

async is true by default so I didnt touched it, Is there anyone who can help me on this, i guess its due to HTTPS.

Async and javascript are essential tags here, Gmail API has nothing to do with it, P.S for Tag editor.

Comment: Cross domain limitation?

Comment: @DevlshOne thanks for the headup but thats not an issue and nothing was reported on console too, the page is on my same domain..

Answer (score 1):

1. Add failure and complete callbacks so that we can see what's happening:
2. Try using a HTTP-specific sniffer like **[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)** (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) - originally written by **Eric Lawrence**, then bought by ***Telerik***.
   It's one of the best (**and FREE**) HTTP / network packet sniffers out there.

   Watch the traffic between your client and server.  In general, look to make sure that everything is OK in terms of TCP/IP for this specific HTTPS connection(request/response) - for instance, make sure that there's a TCP handshake.

   More specifically regarding your code, look for:

   1. **Client-Side:**

      - A successful HTTP request that your browser generated - (cross-reference with Chrome(browser) Network panel) with the proper JSON payload.

        (see [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) to see what this should look like for the jQuery `$.ajax()` call you wrote above
      - Make sure that same successful HTTP request actually left your machine the same way your browser generated it
      - A response of any kind reaching your client from the server
   2. **Server-Side:**

      - Any HTTP request reaching the your server
      - A successful HTTP request reaching the your server
      - Is your server-side code running?
      - Check your logs
      - What's in the DB?
      - Does your PHP code make the request to GMail OK?
      - Use Fiddler to see what's going on between the  *Client* (**your PHP code**) and *Server* (**GMail API**) in your server-side `contacts` API call
      - What does the HTTP response generated from your server look like?
      - Is a successful HTTP response generated reaching your client PC from your server

Answer (score 1):

Can you add `complete`/`failure` callbacks as the other answer suggested like so (this should tell you EXACTLY what's going on):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url :"index.php?page=AJAX&action=importSocial",
  data: {'import':importSource},
  success: function(output) {
    if(output=='multiple'){

      //NOTHING?? IS THAT WHAT YOU MEANT TO DO HERE?

    }
    else{ 
      if(output.indexOf("getFB") >0){
        window.location = output;
        //alert(output+output.length);
      } 
      else{
        window.location = window.location.href;
      }
    }  //END: if(output=='multiple')
  },  //END: `success`:

  /*************************************************
   *  The following assumes jQuery 1.4.x
   *------------------------------------------------
   * <SUMMARY> jQuery 1.4.x `failure` callback function (3 params)</SUMMARY> 
   * <PARAM> jqXHR jqXHR:  jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object </PARAM>
   * <PARAM> String textStatus:
   *   <VALUE> null:  actual null (not a string) if $.ajax() request is successful)</VALUE>
   *   <VALUE> "timeout"</VALUE>
   *   <VALUE> "error"</VALUE>
   *   <VALUE> "abort"</VALUE>
   *   <VALUE> "parsererror"</VALUE>
   * </PARAM>
   * <PARAM> String errorThrown:  HTTP error from Server</PARAM> 
  *************************************************/
  failure: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    if(!textStatus){
      console.err(
        "PROBLEM:  " + 
        "$.ajax() `failure` callback called: " + 
        "`textStatus` = `null` or *empty string*: " + 
        "apparently no $.ajax() request error occurred?"
      ); //END: console.err()
    } //END: if
    else {
      console.err(
        "$.ajax `failure` type \"(0)\"" + 
        "\n" +
        "`HTTP Status` from Server: (1)" + 
        "\n" +
        "`jqXHR object: (2)",
        textStatus,  // 1st replacement (0) - String: $.ajax() status code
        errorThrown, // 2nd replacement (1) - String: HTTP status code
        jqXHR        // 3rd replacement (2) - object: jqXHR object
      ); //END: console.err()
    } //END: else
  }, //END: 'failure`:

  /*************************************************
   *  The following assumes jQuery 1.4.x
   *------------------------------------------------
   * <SUMMARY> 
   *   jQuery 1.4.x `complete` callback function (2 params).
   *   This function is called when the request finishes, i.e.
   *   after the `success` and `error` callbacks are executed. 
   * </SUMMARY> 
   * <PARAM> jqXHR jqXHR:  jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object </PARAM>
   * <PARAM> String textStatus:
   *   <VALUE> "success" </VALUE>
   *   <VALUE> "notmodified" </VALUE>
   *   <VALUE> "nocontent" </VALUE>
   *   <VALUE> "error" </VALUE>
   *   <VALUE> "timeout" </VALUE>
   *   <VALUE> "abort" </VALUE>
   *   <VALUE> "parsererror" </VALUE>
   * </PARAM>
  *************************************************/
  complete: function(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus ){
   if(!textStatus){
      console.err(
        "PROBLEM:  " + 
        "$.ajax() `complete` callback called: " + 
        "`textStatus` = `null` or *empty string*: " + 
        "apparently $.ajax() request didn't complete?"
      ); //END: console.err()
    } //END: if
    else {
      console.err(
        "$.ajax `complete` type: \"(0)\"" + 
        "\n" +
        "`jqXHR object: (1)",
        textStatus,  // 1st replacement (0) - String: $.ajax() status code
        jqXHR        // 2nd replacement (1) - object: jqXHR object
      ); //END: console.err()
    } //END: else
  }, //END: 'complete'
});  //END: $.ajax()
```